# Как сформировать expression аналогичный написанному кодом?

Tags: c#, expressions

У меня сейчас есть примерно такой код:

```
public override Expression<Func<ITask, TaskDto>> ConvertEntityToDto()
{
  return t => t.TypeDiscriminator == guid ? new SimpleTaskDto((ISimpleTask)t) : new TaskDto(t);
}
```

Он отлично работает, возвращает мне иногда `SimpleTaskDto`, иногда `TaskDto`, всё как задумано.

На деле, хочется немного сложнее сделать - на известные в рантайме пары *fooGuid - FooTaskDto* возвращать `FooTaskDto`, на неизвестные - `TaskDto`.

Можно это построить через Expression? Если нельзя, то какие тут есть варианты?

Суть в том, что это часть преобразования сущностей из базы в Dto, и если я выбираю не тот тип, то я теряю часть полезных полей, что вынуждает делать отдельный запрос, хотя я мог бы сделать его прямо тут.

Comment: Хм, а `t.TypeDiscriminator` известен статически? Вы ж не хотите lookup то нему проводить на уровне базы?

Comment: (Или вы не для баз данных? Тогда почему бы не сделать lookup прямо в тексте expression'а?)

Comment: @VladD лучше так, чем отдельный запрос потом. Т.е. lookup меня устроит.

Comment: Так то для базы, но я честно туплю, а как ещё можно обойтись помягче с запросом.

Comment: Окей, а почему тогда не просто `t => (t.TypeDiscriminator == guid1) ? new SimpleTaskDto((ISimpleTask)t) : (t.TypeDiscriminator == guid2) ? new FooTaskDto((IFooTask)t) : new TaskDto(t)`?

Comment: @VladD данные о связи классов и guid появляются только в рантайме нормально. Т.е. в рантайме я буду знать их все, а в момент компиляции - только в своей сборке. Плагины, расширения другими разработчиками.

Comment: Ага, понял. То есть вам нужно сконструировать то же, но динамически?

Comment: @VladD очень хотелось бы.

Comment: Это делается, да. Сейчас попробую (если кто-нибудь не успеет до меня).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите. Вы можете то же самое построить вручную, и добавлять условия итеративно.

Давайте напишем аналог такого выражения:

```
t => t.TypeDiscriminator == guid1 ? new SimpleTaskDto((ISimpleTask)t) :
     t.TypeDiscriminator == guid2 ? new FooTaskDto((IFooTask)t) :
     // тут ещё проверки...
     new TaskDto(t);
```

Вот пример:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ITask), "t");

// new TaskDto(t)
Expression result =
    Expression.New(typeof(TaskDto).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(ITask) }), parameter);

// t.TypeDiscriminator
var typeDiscr = Expression.Property(parameter, "TypeDiscriminator");

// эта часть должна быть в цикле по различным конкретным типам

// параметры конкретной итерации цикла
Guid guid = guid1;
Type parameterType = typeof(ISimpleTask);
Type dtoType = typeof(SimpleTaskDto);

// t.TypeDiscriminator == guid1
var test = Expression.Equal(typeDiscr, Expression.Constant(guid));

// (ISimpleTask)t
var parameterCasted = Expression.Convert(parameter, parameterType);

// (TaskDto)new SimpleTaskDto((ISimpleTask)t)
// каст нужен, чтобы обе части имели общий тип
var altResult = Expression.Convert(
        Expression.New(dtoType.GetConstructor(new[] { parameterType }), parameterCasted),
        typeof(TaskDto));

// аккумулированный результат
result = Expression.Condition(test: test, ifTrue: altResult, ifFalse: result);

// конец цикла тут

// собираем всё в лямбду:
return Expression.Lambda<Func<ITask, TaskDto>>(result, parameter);
```

Comment: Я подобный код сначала читаю снизу вверх, иначе легко запутаться.

Comment: @AK: Я бы упаковал всё в одно выражение, и оно бы хорошо соответствовало дереву. Но в этом случае нельзя дать «говорящие» имена временных переменных.

Comment: `Expression.Condition` выдал 'System.ArgumentException' с текстом - Типы аргумента не совпадают. В переменных - конструкторы SimpleTaskDto и TaskDto. Их надо ещё как то приводить? Вот так у меня выглядит щас код, который правильно собирает цепочки dto - https://gist.github.com/MonkAlex/53f6b018a759c2fbd5d98a3917186b01

Comment: Окей, обновил gist, я добавил конвертацию до базового типа и тогда оно выполняется успешно и визуально дает вполне правильный результат. По возможности - мне бы подсказку, всё нормально сейчас у меня или я что-то упустил или сделал не так?

Comment: @Monk: Я посмотрю, что не так, когда доберусь до компа...

Comment: @Monk: Ага, добавил каст, теперь вроде работает.

Comment: @Monk: Посмотрел gist, да, именно так.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Формирование фильтра сущности на клиентской стороне]У себя в проекте запилил класс, который возвращает список сущностей по отбору, сформированному на клиентской стороне (аналог отбора в 1С). Кратко суть такая: у пользователя на клиентской стороне есть форма в которой он может выбрать поля, способ сравнения и значения для фильтра данных журнала сущности. На сервере это преобразуется в список SelectionSettings (Имя таблицы (строка) Имя колонки (строка), тип колонки (строка) способ сравнения (int) и значение (строка, для списка значений строка с разделителем)). Далее, как и в предыдущих ответах используется Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> и Reflaction

```
public class ExpressionParts
{
    public ExpressionParts() { }

    public Expression Left { get; set; }
    public Expression Right { get; set; }
}
public class SelectionConditionsBuilder<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public SelectionConditionsBuilder() { }
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Condition(List<SelectionSettings> selection)
    {
        Expression condition = null;
        Expression subCondition = null;
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
        if(selection.Count == 0)
        {
            condition = Expression.Constant(true);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(condition, param);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < selection.Count; i++)
        {
            bool skip = false;
            PropertyInfo ptopertyInfo;
            if (selection[i].DataType.IndexOf(".") == -1)
                ptopertyInfo = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(selection[i].TableColumn);
            else
                ptopertyInfo = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(selection[i].TableColumn + "Id");

            foreach (var atr in ptopertyInfo.CustomAttributes)
            {
                if (atr.AttributeType.Name == "NotMappedAttribute")
                {
                    skip = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (skip)
                continue;
            
            switch (selection[i].ComparisonType)
            {
                case ComparisonType.Equals:
                    subCondition = EqualExpression(selection[i], param, ptopertyInfo);
                    break;
                case ComparisonType.NotEqual:
                    subCondition = NotEqualExpression(selection[i], param, ptopertyInfo);
                    break;
                case ComparisonType.More:
                    subCondition = GreaterThanExpression(selection[i], param, ptopertyInfo);
                    break;
                case ComparisonType.MoreOrEqual:
                    subCondition = GreaterThanOrEqualExpression(selection[i], param, ptopertyInfo);
                    break;
                case ComparisonType.Less:
                    subCondition = LessThanExpression(selection[i], param, ptopertyInfo);
                    break;
                case ComparisonType.LessOrEqual:
                    subCondition = LessThanOrEqualExpression(selection[i], param, ptopertyInfo);
                    break;
                case ComparisonType.InList:
                    subCondition = InListExpression(selection[i], param, ptopertyInfo);
                    break;
                case ComparisonType.NotInList:
                    subCondition = NotInListExpression(selection[i], param, ptopertyInfo);
                    break;
            };
            condition = (condition == null ? subCondition : Expression.AndAlso(condition, subCondition));
        }
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(condition, param);
    }

    public Expression GetExpressionLeftPart(ParameterExpression param, PropertyInfo info)
    {
        Expression left = Expression.Property(param, info.Name);
        return left;
    }
    public Expression GetExpressionListRightPart(SelectionSettings setting, PropertyInfo info, string data)
    {
        Expression right = null;
        switch (setting.DataType)
        {
            case "String":
                right = Expression.Constant(data);
                break;
            case "Int32":
                right = Expression.Constant(int.Parse(data));
                break;
            case "Bool":
                right = Expression.Constant(bool.Parse(data));
                break;
            default:
                if (setting.DataType.StartsWith("References."))
                {
                    right = Expression.Constant(int.Parse(data));
                    break;
                }
                break;
        }
        return right;
    }
    public ExpressionParts GetExpressionParts(SelectionSettings setting, ParameterExpression param, PropertyInfo info, int index = -1)
    {
        var parts = new ExpressionParts();
        parts.Left = Expression.Property(param, info.Name);
        string data = setting.SerialisedData;
        switch (setting.DataType)
        {
            case "String":
                parts.Right = Expression.Constant(data);
                break;
            case "Int32":
                parts.Right = Expression.Constant(int.Parse(data));
                break;
            case "Bool":
                parts.Right = Expression.Constant(bool.Parse(data));
                break;
            default:
                if (setting.DataType.StartsWith("References."))
                {
                    parts.Right = Expression.Constant(int.Parse(data));
                    break;
                }
                break;
        }
        return parts;
    }
    public Expression EqualExpression(SelectionSettings setting, ParameterExpression param, PropertyInfo info)
    {
        var parts = GetExpressionParts(setting, param, info);
        return Expression.Equal(parts.Left, parts.Right);
    }
    public Expression NotEqualExpression(SelectionSettings setting, ParameterExpression param, PropertyInfo info)
    {
        var parts = GetExpressionParts(setting, param, info);
        return Expression.NotEqual(parts.Left, parts.Right);
    }
    public Expression GreaterThanExpression(SelectionSettings setting, ParameterExpression param, PropertyInfo info)
    {
        var parts = GetExpressionParts(setting, param, info);
        return Expression.GreaterThan(parts.Left, parts.Right);
    }
    public Expression GreaterThanOrEqualExpression(SelectionSettings setting, ParameterExpression param, PropertyInfo info)
    {
        var parts = GetExpressionParts(setting, param, info);
        return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(parts.Left, parts.Right);
    }
    public Expression LessThanExpression(SelectionSettings setting, ParameterExpression param, PropertyInfo info)
    {
        var parts = GetExpressionParts(setting, param, info);
        return Expression.LessThan(parts.Left, parts.Right);
    }
    public Expression LessThanOrEqualExpression(SelectionSettings setting, ParameterExpression param, PropertyInfo info)
    {
        var parts = GetExpressionParts(setting, param, info);
        return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(parts.Left, parts.Right);
    }
    public Expression InListExpression(SelectionSettings setting, ParameterExpression param, PropertyInfo info)
    {
        Expression inlist = null;
        Expression left = GetExpressionLeftPart(param, info);
        var data = setting.SerialisedData.Split(";");
        foreach(var item in data)
        {
            Expression right = GetExpressionListRightPart(setting, info, item);
            Expression equal = Expression.Equal(left, right);
            inlist = (inlist == null ? equal : Expression.OrElse(inlist, equal));
        }
        return inlist;
    }

    public Expression NotInListExpression(SelectionSettings setting, ParameterExpression param, PropertyInfo info)
    {
        Expression inlist = null;
        Expression left = GetExpressionLeftPart(param, info);
        var data = setting.SerialisedData.Split(";");
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Expression right = GetExpressionListRightPart(setting, info, item);
            Expression equal = Expression.NotEqual(left, right);
            inlist = (inlist == null ? equal : Expression.AndAlso(inlist, equal));
        }
        return inlist;
    }
}
```