# Как динамически сформировать выражение типа Expression<T, bool> для сервиса?

Tags: c#, linq

Имеется модель *EF*:

```
public class OrderDbModel
{
    public bool IsPayed { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Ей соответствует *доменная* модель:

```
public class Order
{
    public bool IsPayed { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Чтобы получить список доменных моделей заказов из сервиса в слое бизнес-логики приложения, предполагается использование следующего *класса-фильтра*:

```
public class OrderFilter
{
    public bool GetUnpayed { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

Для получения списка доменных моделей по фильтру создан *сервис*, который использует репозиторий:

```
public class OrderService
{
    private readonly IOrderRepository _repository;

    public OrderService(IOrderRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Order> GetFilteredOrders(OrderFilter filter)
    {
        // как динамически сформировать выражение???
        Expression<Func<OrderDbModel, bool>> filterExpression = null; 

        var orders = _repository.Get(filterExpression);

        return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OrderDbModel>, IEnumerable<Order>>(orders);
    }
}
```

Собственно, сам вопрос - в комментариях в коде сервиса. Не получается динамически сформировать `filterExpression`. Крайне интересен пример кода для данного конкретного случая с подробным описанием. Имеются ли какие-то библиотеки, которые позволяют это сделать с наименьшими трудозатратами?

**PS:** .NET Framework 4.6, C# 6.

**Пример значений:**
для `OrderFilter` со значениями `{ GetUnpayed = false, Names = new List<string> { "Foo", "Bar" } }` должно плучиться выражение `o => o.IsPayed && (o.Name == "Foo") || o.Name == "Bar")`

Comment: а какое выражение в итоге должно получиться?

Comment: В зависимости от того,  какие значение в объекте класса OrderFilter

Comment: Вот аналогичный вопрос (не дубликат): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/742024/10105

Comment: добавь пример для конкретных значений

Comment: @Grundy , добавил.

Comment: @klutch1991: А, понятно, ну это просто. Я напишу, если никто другой не успеет до меня. // А вы уверены, что Names.Contains выполнится на базе? (Я не знаю, если что, не имел дела с базами.)

Comment: ой ой, пардон, сейчас поправлю, с утра голова не работает))

Comment: @VladD, подправил))

Comment: @klutch1991: Угу, так ещё проще. Доберусь до компа и напишу.

Comment: @VladD, а почему нет?

Comment: @klutch1991, я не вижу связи между `GetUnpayed = false` и `o.IsPayed`. Она есть?

Comment: @Grundy, да, если НЕ выбрать фильтр "Показать неоплаченные", то из бд выбираются только Оплаченные продукты.

Comment: @klutch1991 а не думали регулярки использовать просто? И допустим формировать из регулярок подобные выражения(o => o.IsPayed && (Регулярка1. Соответствует(o.Name)) || Регулярка2. Соответствует(o.Name))

Comment: @klutch1991 подобное можно и на регулярках сделать полностью, но не подходит под вопрос совсем.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

И так, вам нужен способ комбинировать выражения. Проще всего это сделать через операцию *бета-редукции* (т.е. подстановки фактического параметра на место формального).

Для этого понадобится вот такой простейший визитор (visitor, "посетитель"):

```
class Reducer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly IDictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> arguments;

    public Reducer(IDictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> arguments)
    {
        this.arguments = arguments;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        Expression result;
        if (arguments.TryGetValue(node, out result))
            return result;
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Даже если вы не сталкивались с классом ExpressionVisitor ранее - тут все просто. Класс Reducer заменяет в выражении параметры (объекты класса ParameterExpression ) на соответствующие им во входном словаре, если находит их там. Остальные узлы выражения он не трогает.

Теперь можно определить операцию подстановки. Тут все просто: формируем словарь параметров и передаем его классу Reducer после чего прогоняем через Reducer тело лямбда-функции:

```
    public static Expression BetaReduce(this LambdaExpression expr, params Expression[] args)
    {
        Debug.Assert(expr.Parameters.Count == args.Length);
        var mapping = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>();
        for (int i=0; i<expr.Parameters.Count; i++)
            mapping.Add(expr.Parameters[i], args[i]);
        return new Reducer(mapping).Visit(expr.Body);
    }
```

Ну а теперь через операцию BetaReduce уже можно выражать полезные комбинаторы для выражений. Например, комбинатор And:

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] items) => And(items.AsEnumerable());
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> items)
    {
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var body = items.Select(item => item.BetaReduce(p)).Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p);
    }
```

Или комбинатор Or:

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] items) => Or(items.AsEnumerable());
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> items)
    {
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var body = items.Select(item => item.BetaReduce(p)).Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p);
    }
```

Теперь вам ничего не помешает сложить все ваши условия в список, после чего объединить их все через And:

```
var conditions = new List<Expression<Func<OrderDbModel, bool>>>();

if (filter.GetUnpayed)
    conditions.Add(x => !x.IsPayed);
...

var filterExpression = ExpressionUtils.And(conditions);
```

---

Если же вам не нравится работать с выражениями в "сыром" виде, можете попробовать библиотеку [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit).

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Это именно то, что я искал! Отличный ответ.

Comment: как-то сложно получилось

Comment: @Grundy это не сложно, это просто. Удаленный ответ ниже - вот где и правда сложно...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хм, а вы уверены, что ваша β правильная? Например, если у меня есть лямбда `x => coll.Any(y => pred(x, y))`, то заменится как `x`, так и `y`, если я правильно понял.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: А, нет, вроде всё в порядке.